# Can an OS inside Virtualbox work with devices not supported by the parent OS?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to transfer from Windows to Debian.  But, currently Debian just can't connect with my network printer device.  Is it possible to install Windows XP inside a VirtualBox and get it to communicate with the printer device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
It should work out of the box. But it seems overkill to use virtual machine for access to the network printer.
Can you give more details of current problem with connecting to the network printer?

Comment: I'm trying to use a laptop as a server AND to print things on a printer  on my network. And I also thought about dual-boot, but it seems that it's too difficult for me in Debian (Ubuntu did it automatically for me last time, though) Anyway, thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @user531820, if you open a new question and post important stuff like the model of your printer, some smart person will help you set it up. If you can't find a smart person, I might even try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If it's a network device, the host system has no knowledge of that device, except for sharing the network port with the guest OS, so cannot interfere.

You can even try to set up Windows printer sharing from the VM and access that from your host system.

---

USB devices can simply be "attached" to the virtual machine as well, requiring no host system driver.